# Timer to Reset System

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, arduino, reset, pi-b+

Is there a way to make it so my RPi arcade machine will reset after 5 minutes when I press a button (Restart). Can this be done with an arduino?

Comment: Are you familiar with bash scripts or C programming? Should your button be a button on a display or should it be a "hard" button?

Comment: A Button On the GPIO Pins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it so my RPi arcade machine will reset after 5 minutes when I press a button (Restart).

Yes. You connect a button that will execute a timer and `reboot` at the end.

> 

If the Arduino can be rebooted from software, which I presume it can be, yes.  Even if it can't, you could, but you'd have to add some electonics.

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/